# SQL trigger for update

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers

I was just trying to figure out how to do a basic trigger when I updated a row

Heres the setup

```
CREATE TABLE marriage(
personid int
married varchar(20)
);

INSERT INTO marriage
values (1, unmarried);
```

What im trying to do is create a sql trigger that will make it so that when I update a person can only go from married to divorced but not unmarried to divorced.

If anyone can help me with structuring this that would be great

Comment: Update table by stored procedure. And make operatilns inside that procedure. Maybe you do not need to write trigger?

Comment: Careful with this one.  You may start a "holy war".  Some will view this a business logic and state that it has no business in your Storage system.  Others will see no problem with this approach.  But in either case, it is something to think about.

Comment: How is your table updated?

Comment: Where is your problem exactly? What does your trigger look like so far and what is the issue with it?

Comment: Update marriage set marriage.Married = 'divorced' where marriage.person is = 1 //trigger would not allow

Comment: Tip: `inserted` and `deleted` are tables so that they can represent the results of set operations. Designing a trigger on the assumption that it  will always process exactly one row is generally a bad plan. If you are absolutely certain there will never be more than one row then _please_ add a check for the number of rows and use `RaIsError` or `Throw` to explicitly inform those who come along later that they have attempted to execute an unacceptable statement. (`if ( select Count(*) from inserted ) > 1 RaIsError( 'FooTable_Insert: No more than one row may be processed.', 25, 42 ) with log`)

Comment: Tip: It's helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. `sql-server-2014`. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I was looking for if someone was looking for something similar

```
alter trigger
trigtest3
on married
for update
as
begin
    declare @old varchar(20)
    declare @new varchar(20)

    select @old = married from deleted
    select @new = married from inserted
    if(@old like 'Unmarried' AND @new like 'Divorced')
        rollback
end
```

Comment: These solution would only work for one record, if multiple records are updated you are only going to get one row. This is not set based

Comment: You might want to add `RaIsError` or `Throw` when you rollback. Wouldn't you rather get an error like "Cannot change MaritalStatus from 'unmarried' to 'divorced'." rather than a generic insert booboo?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server doesn't provide per-row triggers unfortunately, but only triggers for a complete command. And one single update command can update several rows, so you must look whether at least one affected row has undergone a forbidden change. You do this by joining the `deleted` and `inserted` pseudo tables on a column or a combination of columns that uniquely identify a record (i.e. the primary key).

```
create trigger trg_upd_married on marriage for update as
begin
  declare @error_count int

  select @error_count = count(*)
  from deleted d
  join inserted i on i.id = d.id
  where d.married = 'Unmarried'
  where i.married = 'Divorced'

  if @error_count > 0
  begin
    raiserror('Unmarried persons cannot get divorced.', 16, 121)
    rollback transaction
  end
end;
```

The above trigger may still have errors. I am not fluent with TSQL (and just notice that I find its triggers quite clumsy - at least compared to Oracle's triggers I am used to).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use instead of triggers as you need to prevent update. For update triggers are run after the insert happens. Use the following code -

```
create trigger abc on marriage
for instead of update
as
begin
Begin transaction
if exists(select 1 from deleted as a 
inner join inserted as b
on a.personid = b.personid
where a.married = 'unmarried' and b.married = 'Divorced')
begin
raiserror('Status can not be changed from unmarried to Divorced',16,1)
Rollback transaction
end
else
begin
update a
set a.married = b.married
from marriage as a
inner join inserted as b
on a.personid = b.personid
Commit transaction
end
end
```

Let me know if this helps